# GoogleAnalyticsを導入したサイトで、PHPで生成するCookieをすべてHttpOnlyにして良いか

Tags: javascript, http, security, cookie, google-analytics-api

XSS対策としてCookieをFuelPHPのConfigを用いてHttpOnlyの設定にしようか検討しております。

しかし、実際にHttpOnlyに設定する前と後で、Cookieを見比べてみると
GoogleAnalyticsのCookieである
`_dc_gtm_UA-XXXXXXXXXX=1`
が減っていることがわかりました。

これはGoogle Tag ManagerとGoogle Analyticsの両方を使っているサイトで作成されるCookieのようなので、広告バナーと流入してきたユーザを関連付けするために使われているのか？と思われるのですが、`実際このCookieはどのような時に使われて`、また`無い場合はどのような問題が発生する`のでしょうか？